# Convert NSMutableData to NSData in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdata, nsmutabledata

I have a method which is returning NSMutableData. I need to pass this NSMutableData to another method but that method is expecting only NSData. I am trying to find any method/solution to convert NSMutableData to NSdata. But still no luck.

In Objective C, it can be done like this
NSData *immutableData = [NSData dataWithData:mutableData];

I am not sure how it can be done in Swift?Can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply pass the `NSMutableData` to any method that expects `NSData`. Since it's a subclass, it will work fine.

But if you really want to do the conversion, simply do (Swift 3):

```
let data = someNSMutableDataVariable.copy() as! NSData
```

or

```
let data = NSData(data: someNSMutableDataVariable as Data)
```

It may make sense to update your code to use `Data` instead of `NSMutableData` or `NSData`. Just like using `String` instead of `NSString` and `NSMutableString`.